# Ошибка в книге Byte of python в таблице 5.1 (таблица операторов)

Tags: python

Всем здравствуйте. Решил перечитать первую половину книги Byte of python для закрепления, столкнулся с непониманием понятия деление по модулю, начал гуглить. Понял суть. Решил вручную перепроверить пример из таблицы (25.5 % 2.25) получилось 0.75, тогда как в учебнике ( и в оригинале и в переводе) [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] результат равен 1.5.  Перепроверял этот пример на нескольких интерпретаторах, на пк, онлайн, на калькуляторе, в голове. Всегда получается 0.75. Почитал полезную статью на эту тему вот здесь: [PYTHON - курс молодого бойца](https://https:chel-center.ru/python-yfc/2021/04/29/delenie-po-modulyu-v-praktike-python-ili-kak-ispolzovat-operator/)

Воспользовался Math.fmod(), как рекомендовано там, ещё раз все перепроверил, всё так же 0.75.
Сам вопрос: это действительно ошибка (опечатка) в книге, или это у меня лыжи не едут?
P.S. Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся и прошу прощения, если задаю глупый вопрос, ибо я только начал изучение этого дела, и просто хочу разобраться во всем, с чем сталкиваюсь по мере обучения.

Comment: `-25.5 % 2.25` <- обратите внимание на минус (в англ. версии оторван от числа).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!!! Я этот минус ( учусь по русской версии книги) воспринял как символ разделения примеров,  то есть пример 1-пример 2., А оказывается это минус. элементарное отсутствие разделения ( например ;) заморочило мне всю голову.